# Плагин галереи для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин для ВП, что бы можно было публиковать серии фотографий. 
Т.е. одна за одной в записи. Примеры:
http://pavel-melnik.com/pomnit-tvoi-ruki-volnyi/
http://vladimirtsarkov.com/blog/elizaveta-i-timofej

Answer (score 0):

У Мельника сайт на WordPress. Судя по коду, тема заказная, галерея реализована через произвольный тип записей.

Плагинов для галерей - масса, например, [Robo Gallery](http://robosoft.co/robogallery/). Практически все имеют параметр - количество изображений в ряд. Поставьте 1 - и будет то самое, о чем вопрос, плюс масса доп. возможностей.